# Exception when accessing a class defined in library project from another project

Tags: android, eclipse, project, noclassdeffounderror

I have 2 projects in Eclipse. One is a library project (the base project) and one is the project that will be released as the free version of the app. The free project has only 1 activity in it: a LaunchActivity. Everything else is in the library project.

I try to debug the free project and the 1st time I try to reference a class defined in the Library project, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. At one point I couldn't even use the library classes in the free project until I went on the free project, right-clicked Properties > Java Build Path > Projects tab and included the library project (although I figured this would be taken care of by adding the library project as a reference in Properties > Android and adding the reference). I have even tried Properties > Project References and added the library proj as a reference here too but without success.

Any ideas?

Many many thanks,
Sean

Comment: It is very simple to reproduce: Create an Android Project, make it a library (Properties > Android > IsLibrary checked). Create another Android Project, make this one reference the lib project (Properties > Android > Library > Add). Add a class to the lib project with some static member in it. Try to access this member in the other project. Boom! NoClassDefFoundError. This is something that is so trivial normally, what am I doing wrong?!?!

Comment: Well, I'm slowly moving onto other stuff. Hopefully if this can save anybody the nightmare I went through. Basically what I did was re-install the latest android sdk (which brought on a whole other list of pbs due to adb.exe getting moved) and once i reopened eclipse, i loaded 2 sample projects to follow exactly what they did (tictactoelib and main). Since then, I noticed that once the lib project was declared as a library and ref'd by the other prj, i noticed in the project explorer a new entry in the other prj (libproject_src [Android Library]). since it was worked well

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your activities that are defined in library Project's AndroidManifest.xml into Main projects AndroidManifest.xml also.

And ,include library project as a reference through Properties->Android->Add->Apply